# Formatting of Complex Numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, complex-numbers

How can complex numbers be formatted in Google sheets? If for instance I have the following complex number in a cell, with both real and imaginary part too long for my needs,

```
=COMPLEX(1.23456789, 0.987654321)
```

which would be displayed as

```
1.23456789+0.987654321i
```

where is the format accessible so that it is displayed as in the following?

```
1.23+0.99i
```

Answer (score 1):

this maybe:

```
=COMPLEX(ROUND(1.23456789,2), ROUND(0.987654321,2))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this modifies the number, not format it.